# asp.net core identity RoleTable's RoleId as foreign key

Tags: c#, identity, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

This is asp.net core identity role table structure .

```
    AspNetRoles
 -------------------
-id (PrimaryKey)
-ConcurrencyStamp
-Name
-NormalizedName
```

I want to create a new table including this role table's `id` as foreign key.
Here is my poco for new table

```
  public class NewClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Type { get; set; }

    //
}
```

How can I reference AspNetRoles's id as foreign key with many-to-one relationship  ??

Comment: do you need multiple role for a class??

Comment: yes , NewClass --> manyToOne ---> AspNetRoles

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this

```
public class AspNetRoles
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NormalizedName{ get; set; }

    public List<NewClass> NewClasses{ get; set; }
}

public class NewClass
{
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public int Type { get; set; }

   public int RoleId { get; set; }
   public AspNetRoles AspNetRole{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am little bit confused which side is your many and which side is one.
If you are using entity framework then just Try with this example.Entity framework is intelligent enough to make one to many relation between them

**if your many side is NewClass then try with this.OR if you need multiple role in your NewClass**

```
    public class AspNetRole
    {
      public int RoleId { get; set; }    
      public string Name { get; set; }     
    }



   public class NewClass
   {
    ..................
    ................

    public ICollection<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles{ get; set; }
   }
```

**If your Many side is Roles then try with this**

```
    public class AspNetRole
   {
      public int RoleId { get; set; }    
      public string Name { get; set; }  
      public ICollection<NewClass> NewClasses{ get; set; }   
    }



  public class NewClass
  {
   ................

    public int AspNetRolesId{ get; set; }
    public AspNetRole AspNetRoles{ get; set; }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do this:

**OneToZore:**

For `One` to `Zore` from `AspNetRoles` like:

```
Public class AspNetRole
{
    //Other property
    public int NewClassId { get; set; }
}

public class NewClass
{
    //Other property
    public AspNetRole AspNetRole { get; set; }
}
```

For One to Zore from `NewClass`:

```
Public class AspNetRole
{
    //Other property
    public NewClass NewClass { get; set; }
}

public class NewClass
{
    //Other property
    public int AspNetRoleId { get; set; }
}
```

**OneToMany:**

For `One` to `Many` from AspNetRole:

```
Public class AspNetRole
{
    //Other property
    public int NewClassId { get; set; }
}

public class NewClass
{
    //Other property
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
}
```

For `One` to `Many` from NewClass:

```
Public class AspNetRole
{
    //Other property
    public virtual ICollection<NewClass> NewClasses { get; set; }
}

public class NewClass
{
    //Other property
    public int AspNetRoleId { get; set; }
}
```

**ManyToMany:**

For this issue you can not create this as directly, you have to find a table that has relation with that table. For example `User` table has a relation(One to Many) with `AspNetRole` like:

```
Public class AspNetRole
{
    //Other property
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    //Other property
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Now If you have relation as `OneToMany` with `User` table, after that you have a relation as `ManyToMany` with AspNetRole like:

```
Public class AspNetRole
{
    //Other property
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    //Other property
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NewClass> NewClasses { get; set; }
}

public class NewClass
{
    //Other property
    public int AspNetRoleId { get; set; }
}
```